# Binding list of objects to the controller with Spring MVC

Tags: arrays, spring-mvc, binding, tomcat7, java-7

I did some research for this problem and still its not working for me

I'm using Spring mvc 3.1 , java 7 and tomcat 7.0.62

when I try to post the form to the controller, tomcat returns 400 incorrect syntax

for example:

```
//the class I intent to use as list of objects
public class data {
    private Integer a;
    private Integer b;
    //getters , setters and constructor
}

//the controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ModelAttribute("something")
public ModelAndView test(@RequestParam(value="fromForm") List<data> fromForm, BindingResult result, ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request)throws Exception {
   //do something
}


<!-- part from the form , from the .jsp file-->
<form:form method="POST" action="test.htm" >
<table>
<c:forEach var="something" items="${someItems} varStatus ="current">
<tr>
<td><input type="number" name="fromForm.a" /></td>
<td><input type="number" name="fromForm.b" /></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>

</form:form>
```

I tried setting the name of the input field

```
fromForm${current.index}.a
fromForm[${current.index}].a
```

doesn't do the trick

till now I only succeeded binding primitive types like 
sending parameters to

```
@RequestParam(value="fromForm") List<Integer> fromForm
```

from single input fields .

this does some trick , but after I need to put them together in the controller

Comment: Can you provide the stacktrace?

Comment: I'll try to get some but its happening before it get to the controller , there are no errors only 400 from tomcat, what I want to accomplish is to get list of objects from every row in a table I'm currently doing it by  making a loop as the amount of rows  and pulling the parameters of the object from the request manually , and than create object and add it to a list

Comment: that does the trick but binding the list of beans should do too , and its more friendly to work wit the user inputs later.
The one thing I haven't tried yet is making transient list of objects in the model bean and try binding the form there